# In SQL, find duplicates in one column with unique values for another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table of aliases linked to record ids. I need to find duplicate aliases with unique record ids. To explain better:

```
ID    Alias     Record ID
1     000123    4
2     000123    4
3     000234    4
4     000123    6
5     000345    6
6     000345    7
```

The result of a query on this table should be something to the effect of

```
000123    4    6
000345    6    7
```

Indicating that both record 4 and 6 have an alias of 000123 and both record 6 and 7 have an alias of 000345.

I was looking into using GROUP BY but if I group by alias then I can't select record id and if I group by both alias and record id it will only return the first two rows in this example where both columns are duplicates. The only solution I've found, and it's a terrible one that crashed my server, is to do two different selects for all the data and then join them

```
ON [T_1].[ALIAS] = [T_2].[ALIAS] AND NOT [T_1].[RECORD_ID] = [T_2].[RECORD_ID]
```

Are there any solutions out there that would work better? As in, not crash my server when run on a few hundred thousand records?

Comment: I hear "pivot" calling

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks as if you have two requirements:

1. Identify all aliases that have more than one record id, and
2. List the record ids for these aliases horizontally.

The first is a lot easier to do than the second.  Here's some SQL that ought to get you where you want with the first:

```
WITH A   -- Get a list of unique combinations of Alias and [Record ID]
AS  (
   SELECT Distinct
          Alias
     ,    [Record ID]
   FROM  T1
)
,   B  -- Get a list of all those Alias values that have more than one [Record ID] associated
AS  (
    SELECT Alias
    FROM   A
    GROUP BY
           Alias
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT  A.Alias
    ,   A.[Record ID]
FROM    A
    JOIN B
        ON  A.Alias = B.Alias
```

Now, as for the second.  If you're satisfied with the data in this form:

```
Alias     Record ID
000123    4
000123    6
000345    6
000345    7
```

... you can stop there.  Otherwise, things get tricky.

The PIVOT command will *not* necessarily help you, because it's trying to solve a different problem than the one you have.

I am assuming that you can't necessarily predict how many duplicate `Record ID` values you have per `Alias`, and thus don't know how many columns you'll need.

If you have only two, then displaying each of them in a column becomes a relatively trivial exercise.  If you have more, I'd urge you to consider whether the destination for these records (a report?  A web page?  Excel?) might be able to do a better job of displaying them horizontally than SQL Server can do in returning them arranged horizontally.

Comment: If A is defined with Select Distinct, how would B contain anything? It is pulling from A with Count > 1 but everything in A is distinct...

Comment: A has Alias and [Record ID], so the DISTINCT will make sure that you have distinct *combinations* of those two.  B groups by just Alias, so if you have more than one case in A of the same Alias (but with different [Record ID] values), that Alias will be returned.  The final query combines them:  show those values from A that appear in B: the combinations of Alias and [Record ID] that belong to Alias values that had more than one [Record ID] associated with them.

Comment: How could I run an update on the results of this query? Eg. change RecordID=4 where RecordID=2 just in these results.

Comment: @robertwoods Sorry it's taken me a LONG time to get back to you.  Do you still have a question, or are things taken care of?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is just the `min()` and `max()` of `RecordId`:

```
select Alias, min(RecordID), max(RecordId)
from yourTable t
group by Alias
having min(RecordId) <> max(RecordId)
```

You can also count the number of distinct values, using `count(distinct)`:

```
select Alias, count(distinct RecordId) as NumRecordIds, min(RecordID), max(RecordId)
from yourTable t
group by Alias
having count(DISTINCT RecordID) > 1;
```

Comment: Since she's specifically looking for duplicates, I would add to your query:    " HAVING Count(distinct RecordId) > 1 "

Answer (score 0):

This will give all repeated values:

```
select Alias, count(RecordId) as NumRecordIds,  
from yourTable t
group by Alias
having count(RecordId) <> count(distinct RecordId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ann L's answer but would like to show how you can use window functions with CTE's as you may prefer the readability.

(Re: how to pivot horizontally, I again agree with Ann)

```sql
create temporary table things (
  id serial primary key,
   alias varchar,
   record_id int
)

insert into things (alias, record_id) values 
('000123', 4),
('000123', 4),
('000234', 4),
('000123', 6),
('000345', 6),
('000345', 7);
```

```sql
with 
    things_with_distinct_aliases_and_record_ids as (
        select distinct on (alias, record_id)
               id, 
             alias, 
             record_id 
             from things
    ),
    things_with_unique_record_id_counts_per_alias as (
        select *,
             COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY alias) as unique_record_ids_count
             from things_with_distinct_aliases_and_record_ids
  ) 

select * from things_with_unique_record_id_counts_per_alias
       where unique_record_ids_count > 1
```

The first CTE gets all the unique alias/record id combinations. E.g.

```
 id | alias  | record_id
----+--------+-----------
  1 | 000123 |         4
  4 | 000123 |         6
  3 | 000234 |         4
  5 | 000345 |         6
  6 | 000345 |         7
```

The second CTE simply creates a new column for the above and adds the count of record ids for each alias. This allows you to filter only those aliases which have more than one record id associated with them.

```
 id | alias  | record_id | unique_record_ids_count
----+--------+-----------+-------------------------
  1 | 000123 |         4 |                       2
  4 | 000123 |         6 |                       2
  3 | 000234 |         4 |                       1
  5 | 000345 |         6 |                       2
  6 | 000345 |         7 |                       2
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT A.CitationId,B.CitationId, A.CitationName, A.LoaderID, A.PrimaryReferenceLoaderID,B.SecondaryReference1LoaderID, A.SecondaryReference1LoaderID, A.SecondaryReference2LoaderID, 
 A.SecondaryReference3LoaderID, A.SecondaryReference4LoaderID, A.CreatedOn, A.LastUpdatedOn 
FROM CitationMaster A, CitationMaster B
WHERE A.PrimaryReferenceLoaderID= B.SecondaryReference1LoaderID and Isnull(A.PrimaryReferenceLoaderID,'') != '' and Isnull(B.SecondaryReference1LoaderID,'') !=''
```